# Pyomo: Derived component IndexedConstraint failed to define _default()

Tags: pyomo

I use pyomo develop an energy optimization model, however it got some error when I add a wind turbine constraint like:  **`return Sys.Power_WT_Unit[i]== 0.5*(Sys.WindSpeed[i]**3)`**.

it says

> DeveloperError: Internal Pyomo implementation error:'Derived component
>   IndexedConstraint failed to define _default().'"

## Anyone can help? Following is the whole error contents

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint Power_WT_Unit with index 1:
        DeveloperError: Internal Pyomo implementation error:
                'Derived component IndexedConstraint failed to define _default().'
                Please report this to the Pyomo Developers. ERROR: Constructing component 'Power_WT_Unit' from data=None failed:
        DeveloperError: Internal Pyomo implementation error:
                'Derived component IndexedConstraint failed to define _default().'
                Please report this to the Pyomo Developers. Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-f74e8c884272>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Koo/Documents/GitHub/EIS-Opt_Ver20180127/EIS-Opt.py', wdir='C:/Users/Koo/Documents/GitHub/EIS-Opt_Ver20180127')

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Koo/Documents/GitHub/EIS-Opt_Ver20180127/EIS-Opt.py", line 23, in <module>
    instance  = SysResolution(Sys) # Add Constraints and solving the problem

  File "SysResolution.py", line 75, in SysResolution
    instance = Sys.create_instance(datapath) # load parameters

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py", line 714, in create_instance
    report_timing=report_timing )

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py", line 785, in load
    report_timing=report_timing)

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py", line 861, in _load_model_data
    self._initialize_component(modeldata, namespaces, component_name, profile_memory)

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py", line 920, in _initialize_component
    declaration.construct(data)

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\constraint.py", line 761, in construct
    ndx)

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\misc.py", line 61, in apply_indexed_rule
    return rule(model, index)

  File "Constraints.py", line 147, in Power_WT_Unit
    return Sys.Power_WT_Unit[i]== 0.5*(Sys.WindSpeed[i]**3)

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\indexed_component.py", line 493, in __getitem__
    return self._default(ndx)

  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\indexed_component.py", line 656, in _default
    % (self.__class__.__name__,))

DeveloperError: Internal Pyomo implementation error:    'Derived component IndexedConstraint failed to define _default().'
```

Please report this to the Pyomo Developers.

Answer (score 0):

This error was reported in https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/9 and fixed in https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/133.  The fix will be included in the Pyomo 5.4 release.

That said, there is something suspect in your model: the root cause appears to be that `Sys.Power_WT_Unit` is declared as a Constraint in your model, but you are using it within an expression.  The actual error is probably because the rule that is firing is trying to retrieve the i'th index of `Power_WT_Unit` before that component was (fully) constructed.